# How to see primary key id field in sqllite in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve a row id (_id) from sql table that I've created on android with auto increment
I can see all the other fields in the table except the primary key field.
this id the code of the table :

```
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String JOKE = "Joke";
public static final String AUTHOR = "Author";
public static final String DATE = "Date";
public static final String STATUS = "Status"; 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " 
            + ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " 
            + JOKE + " TEXT, " 
            + AUTHOR + " TEXT, " 
            + DATE + " DATE, " 
            + STATUS + " TEXT " 
            + ")");         
    }
```

When I'm trying to receive the index of the field I receive -1 for the field ID

```
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int authorColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("Author");
        int statusColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("Status"); 
        int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("Date");
```

I can see the index for all other fields but the key field ( _id )
anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cur.getColumnIndex("_id")` returning `-1` means that this column does not exist in the `Cursor`. Assuming that you pass the projection (`null` here) inside your `ContentProvider` unaltered to the correct table you can be sure that this column does not exist in the database.

The usual reason is that you added / renamed the column in a later stage but forgot to upgrade your database to the new version. That is not happening automatically.

Bump the database version in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` or delete your app data from the system settings to see if that adds the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your key this way:

```
id = cur.getInt(0);
```